# Using transition with :target

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

Got a question regarding transition with :target-selector. 
Tried to google and search the internet for ways to get the transition working with my code, but I only got animation to work (which I am not allowed to use).

My HTML code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BluShop</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <header id="header">
        <h1>BluShop</h1>
    </header>

    <section id="leftContent">
        <div id="pacificrimContent">
            <h2>Pacific Rim</h2>
            <img src="../bilder/pacificRim.jpg">
            <p>blahblah</p>
        </div>
        <div id="startrekContent">
            <h2>Star Trek</h2>
            <img src="../bilder/starTrek.jpg">
            <p>blahblah</p>
        </div>
        <div id="worldwarzContent">
            <h2>World War Z</h2>
            <img src="../bilder/worldWarZ.jpg">
            <p>blahblah </p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <aside id="rightContent">
        <div id="pacificrimPoster">
            <a href="#pacificrimContent"><img src="../bilder/pacificRim.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="startrekPoster">
            <a href="#startrekContent"><img src="../bilder/starTrek.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="worldwarzPoster">
            <a href="#worldwarzContent"><img src="../bilder/worldWarZ.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <footer id="footer">
    </footer>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS code:

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    margin: 0;
    }

#container{
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgb(78, 80, 85);
    border: solid 1px rgb(213, 214, 215);
    }

#header{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(66, 69, 74);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }   

#header h1{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    color: rgb(14, 177, 238);   
    }

#leftContent{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;;
    height: 460px;
    width: 780px;
    background-color: rgb(230, 231, 232);
    }

#leftContent h2{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    }

#leftContent img{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 20px 10px 10px;
    width: 310px;
    height: 420px;
    }

#leftContent p{
    margin: -4px 20px 10px 0px;
    }           

#pacificrimContent, #startrekContent, #worldwarzContent{
    display: none;
    }   

#rightContent{
    float: right;
    width: 140px;
    height: 460px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: rgb(230, 231, 232);
    }   

#rightContent img{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px    
    }

#pacificrimContent:target{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    }   

#startrekContent:target{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    }

#worldwarzContent:target{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    }   

#footer{
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;  
    background-color: rgb(16, 163, 210);
    clear: both;
    }
```

The images that gona be showing up when using :target has to be unvisiable first, therefor have I been using display: none, under the #pacificrimContent, etc..

So what I look after is that when I trigger the #pacificrimContent to appear I want a transition effect, as f.ex. a fade in effect. I have tried differnets ways: as placing the transition: all 2s fadein; under the display: none, but I can't get this to work out.

It would be fine if someone could help me on my way her. I also would be glad if people explain it to so I can learn what I am actually doing and just not using copy/pasye.

Thanks!

Comment: Using `display` property always causes transitions to break.

Comment: Ah, I see. So to use the visibility-property is the way to go then?

Comment: You can try by setting height of the target box as 0 on start and then transition it to 100% like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Yfys4/). If this solution is Ok for you, I will add it as answer.

Comment: Thank you. That worked like a dream. I also learned, thanks to you, that I can't use display-property with transition. So you saved me some time in the futere. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of the `display` property (that is, changing `display` from `none` to `block` or vice-versa) always causes transitions to break.

As an alternate option, you can set the `height` of the block to `0` initially and then transition it to `100%` when targeted. Below is a sample:

```
#pacificrimContent, #startrekContent, #worldwarzContent {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}
#pacificrimContent:target, #startrekContent:target, #worldwarzContent:target {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 960px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgb(78, 80, 85);
  border: solid 1px rgb(213, 214, 215);
}
#header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(66, 69, 74);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#header h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  color: rgb(14, 177, 238);
}
#leftContent {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  height: 460px;
  width: 780px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 231, 232);
}
#leftContent h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
#leftContent img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px 10px 10px;
  width: 310px;
  height: 420px;
}
#leftContent p {
  margin: -4px 20px 10px 0px;
}
#pacificrimContent,
#startrekContent,
#worldwarzContent {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}
#rightContent {
  float: right;
  width: 140px;
  height: 460px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 231, 232);
}
#rightContent img {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px
}
#pacificrimContent:target,
#startrekContent:target,
#worldwarzContent:target {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(16, 163, 210);
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header id="header">
    <h1>BluShop</h1>

  </header>
  <section id="leftContent">
    <div id="pacificrimContent">
      <h2>Pacific Rim</h2>

      <img src="../bilder/pacificRim.jpg">
      <p>blahblah</p>
    </div>
    <div id="startrekContent">
      <h2>Star Trek</h2>

      <img src="../bilder/starTrek.jpg">
      <p>blahblah</p>
    </div>
    <div id="worldwarzContent">
      <h2>World War Z</h2>

      <img src="../bilder/worldWarZ.jpg">
      <p>blahblah</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <aside id="rightContent">
    <div id="pacificrimPoster">
      <a href="#pacificrimContent">
        <img src="../bilder/pacificRim.jpg">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div id="startrekPoster">
      <a href="#startrekContent">
        <img src="../bilder/starTrek.jpg">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div id="worldwarzPoster">
      <a href="#worldwarzContent">
        <img src="../bilder/worldWarZ.jpg">
      </a>

    </div>
  </aside>
  <footer id="footer"></footer>
</div>
```

**Use the below links to get the list of Animatable/Transitionable properties:**

1. [W3C List](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties-)
2. [MDN List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)